# I am getting error while trying to create report through cmd

Tags: jmeter

I am seeing error
'-n' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I added path in the Env and When I try to run this command to generate report
C:\Users\ashwi>>jmeter -n -t "C:\Users\ashwi\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.6\apache-jmeter-5.6\bin\ccce.jmx" -l "C:\Users\ashwi\OneDrive\Desktop\Result1.csv" -e -o "C:\Users\ashwi\OneDrive\Desktop\Reports"

I am seeing above error. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to remove this `>` in the beginning of your command

[image]

As `>` is a [reserved special character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Windows_Command_Prompt) which means redirection

More information: [JMeter Non-GUI Mode: Useful Tips](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode)